# svg - Задать фон под изображение

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

```css
svg {height:60px}
ellipse {
    cx:7.5;
    cy:1.8;
    ry:2;
    rx:2;
    fill: red; 
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: .4
}
text {
    text-anchor:middle;
    dominant-baseline:central;
    font-size: .15em; 
    background: red;
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <defs>
    <rect id="rect" x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="80%" rx="15" fill="rgb(93,59,174, 60%);"/>
    <clipPath id="clip"><use xlink:href="#rect"/></clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Circle-icons-profile.svg/1200px-Circle-icons-profile.svg.png" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
  <ellipse></ellipse>
  <text x="7.5" y="1.8">10</text>
</svg>
```

Каким образом, возможно задать фон под изображение под тот же радиус?

Второй вопрос, возможно ли что проще сделать. В плане меньше кода и

10

Смущает, оба блока необходимо выравнивать, координаты задавать. Возможно ли проще и в этом плане сделать?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes

Comment: Не fill ни stoke,  не работают...

Comment: что значит задать фон под тот же радиус?

Comment: Просто, чтобы под изображением был фон.

Comment: Дал ответ ниже "Чтобы под изображением был фон"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
svg {height:60px}
ellipse {
    cx:7.5;
    cy:1.8;
    ry:2;
    rx:2;
    fill: red; 
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: .4
}
text {
    text-anchor:middle;
    dominant-baseline:central;
    font-size: .15em; 
    background: red;
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  
    <rect style="fill: skyblue;" id="rect" x="10%" y="10%" width="80%" height="80%" rx="15" fill="rgb(93,59,174, 60%);"/>
    <clipPath id="clip"><use xlink:href="#rect"/></clipPath> 
  <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Circle-icons-profile.svg/1200px-Circle-icons-profile.svg.png" height="100%" clip-path="url(#clip)"/>
  <ellipse></ellipse>
  <text x="7.5" y="1.8">10</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Фон необходим под изображением, так чтобы он не выходил за границы радиуса изображения.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов так его видно не будет, у вас png без просрачности

Comment: Я понимаю, но необходим фон  именно под изображение. На тот случаи если изображение не погрузится...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Исправил ответ

Comment: Работает. Еще просьба, возможно оставить все тоже самое, просто кода в блоке svg поменьше.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов нет, невозможно, если только сохранить этот код в файл c svg расширением

Comment: <ellipse></ellipse><text x="7.5" y="2.5">10</text>, Приходится каждый из элементов фиксить, координаты по x и y. Возможно выполнить так, чтобы задать координаты родителю, а текст выровнять по центру. В идеале было бы если родитель имел окружность красного цвета, а текст в нем был выровнян по центру.